# PHP merge two arrays like in javascript's push([[],[]])

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays which I want to combine in PHP:

```
Array1 = [123,456,789];

Array2 = [1,2,3];
```

I want to combine them as follows:

```
Array3 = [[123,1],[456,2],[789,3]];
```

In Javascript I can use the function push() in a forloop which looks like this:

```
Array3.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
```

But I can't seem to figure out why this isn't possible with PHP? I have tried using

```
array_merge(array1,array2);
array3 = array1 + array2;
```

But neither works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?
You might need to add null-checks if you want.

```
function array_combinemerge($arr1, $arr2) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++)
        $result[] = array($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
    return $result;
}
```

Example code:

```
// example code
$Array1 = array(123,456,789);
$Array2 = array(1,2,3);
$Combined = array_combinemerge($Array1, $Array2);
print_r($Combined);
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the help man. As for the output the arrays are used to make a chart: http://imgur.com/a/jULvJ which is the same output I got from the javascript version. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
$a1 = [123,456,789];
$a2 = [1,2,3];

$a3 = [];

foreach($a1 as $key => $item){
 $a3[$key] = [$a1[$key], $a2[$key]];
}

print_r($a3);  // [[123,1],[456,2],[789,3]];
```

> It's not very flexible, but it resolves this particular situation.

#### [You can test it here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c66d41a992c848c5bc8fa359e52829c734c97473)

Comment: Thanks, work just as fine as @Cra4xy answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @TarikM no problem, glad I could help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = [123,456,789];
$a2 = [1,2,3];
$a = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
    return [$a, $b];
}, $a1, $a2);

print_r($a);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but better you could vote for the best answer of the question. So at least readers in future might see how to code in the best way ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$arr_a = [1,2,3];
$arr_b = [4,5,6];

$combined = array_map(function($k,$v)use($arr_b){
   return array($v, $arr_b[$k]);
}, $arr_a);
```